# How to evaluate expressions in Mathematica from MATLAB?

Tags: interoperability, matlab

I found a lot of information and examples on how to communicate from Mathematica to Matlab using MATLink, but nothing for the other way around. I would like to use Matlab to send variables and equations to Mathematica, let Mathematica calculate some stuff, and receive the output in Matlab again.

Are there any packages that can do this?

Comment: This package claims to do this, but I have never used it. It probably needs to be brought up to date to work in recent versions of Mathematica. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6044-mathematica-symbolic-toolbox-for-matlab-version-2-0

Comment: This is a valid question, but as said above, not really about MATLink. Thus I removed that tag.

Comment: Have you tried `Input[]` and `Export[]`?